# Convergence of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Given the stochastic differential equation:

$dx=-xdt+dW$

and the initial condition $\left(  t_{0},x_{0}\right)  $, the solution
trajectory $x\left(  t;t_{0},x_{0}\right)  $ can be derived by variation of
constants as

$
x\left(  t;t_{0},x_{0}\right)  =x_{0}e^{-\left(  t-t_{0}\right)  }+\int
_{t_{0}}^{t}e^{-\left(  t-s\right)  }dW\left(  s\right)
$

The expectation is shown to be
$
E\left[  x\left(  t;t_{0},x_{0}\right)  \right]  =x_{0}e^{-\left(
t-t_{0}\right)  }
$. 
Given $a>0$, the probability of $x\left(  t\right)  $ to be in the open set
$\left(  -a,a\right)  $ is

$
P\left[  x\left(  t\right)  \in\left(  -a,a\right)  \right]  =1-P\left[  \left\vert x\left(  t\right)  \right\vert
\geq a\right]
$

By virtue of the Markov inequality
$
P\left[  \left\vert x\left(  t\right)  \right\vert \geq a\right]  \leq
\frac{\left\vert x_{0}\right\vert e^{-\left(  t-t_{0}\right)  }}{a}
$
and taking the limit as $t\rightarrow\infty$, $P\left[  \left\vert x\left(
t\right)  \right\vert \geq a\right]  $ converges to zero.

My main concern has to do with $x\left(  t\right)  $. The solution is an
Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process and as a consequence it becomes a Gaussian
distribution. This indicates that $x\left(  t\right)  $ exists in any large
region on $\mathbb{R}$ with non-zero probability for any $t$. This indicates
that the solution cannot converge to a compact set. However
$
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}P\left[  x\left(  t\right)  \in\left(  -a,a\right)
\right]  =1
$
that is the trajectory converges to the compact set $\left[  -a,a\right]  $.
What is wrong in this reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

You have $\mathbb{E}[X(t)] = x_0 e^{-(t-t_0)}$, but you applied Markov's inequality to $|X(t)|$, effectively turning $\mathbb{E}[|X(t)|]$ into $\mathbb{E}[X(t)]$. To exaggerate the mistake, you could have said that if $Z \sim N(0,1)$, then $$P(|Z| \geq a) \leq \frac{E[Z]}{a} = 0.$$